# How to find parameters from logistic equation

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an function and assume that that is convex function. I want to use gradient decent to find parameters in that equation. Could you suggest to me the way to do it. Thanks. This is my function
$$J=\int B(x) \times \left[\frac {1}{1+e^{-{ax+b}}}-L \right ]^2$$
where $L=\{-1;1\}$, B is Gaussian kernel that such that $\int B(x)=1$

How to find $a$,$b$ subject to $min_{a,b}J$

That mean I will compute 
$$\frac {\partial J}{\partial a}=0$$ 
$$\frac {\partial J}{\partial b}=0$$

Could you help me find two above equation?

Comment: Why do you assume it is convex? That's actually a poor assumption to make without specific evidence. Most functions aren't.

Comment: Actually, square function is convex function. I just multiple with a kernel B. The kernel B is also convex function, So total is convex function.

Comment: Yes, the square is convex. The square *of another nonlinear function* is not necessarily so. You have some work to do to prove convexity.

Comment: Actually, No. But that model is often appear in many paper in my research. It did not prove that it is convex function. Just get gradient decent without proving

Comment: Fair enough. Gradient descent will likely converge to a local minimum. And who knows, you might get lucky and hit the global minimum, too!

Comment: Right. However, the local optimal is very near with global optimal in my problem. So, it can use local minimal.

Comment: Back to the original problem, I seriously doubt you will find any way to analytically solve for the optimal conditions. A numerical descent method is going to be your best bet.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Please see the original paper. He used gradient decent to find the parameters. http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/2013papers/gjkw/gk45.pdf